# NextJS getting 404 with basePath and Apache2 proxy

Tags: proxy, next.js

I want to deploy my NextJs app to my Pi4 where i have multiple active services. So I use a proxy from `http://MYDOMAIN/convert/` to `http://localhost:3000` but when I open the page in the Browser I get alot of 404 Errors. What throws me of is that I can see the nextjs error page. Is there a solution to that?

**next.config.js:**

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    basePath: isProd ? '/convert' : '',
    assetPrefix: isProd ? '/convert/' : '',
}
```

**additional apache.conf:**

```
ProxyPass /convert http://localhost:3000/
```

[404 Errors on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeRWi.png)

Comment: Are you running the Next.js app in [production mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production) (`next build && next start`)?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: I have not fiexed it and im running it in production mode

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same issue.

Initially in apache.conf I have added the following rule.

```
ProxyPass /former/ http://localhost:3050/
```

It started working after updating it with the following

```
ProxyPass /former/ http://localhost:3050/former/
```